# Ionic - using CapacitorHttp true and false in the same app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have an Ionic Project that call some API's. Some require CapacitorHttp to be enabled to work, some required to be disabled to work.

Problem this is an app configuration :

```
  webDir: 'www',
  "plugins": {
    "CapacitorHttp": {
      "enabled": **false**
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to enable and disable CapacitorHttp programatically in the app? if not is there a way to do a kind of 2nd process in the app one running CapacitorHttp enabled, the other not?

Thanks